# Haskell: Couldn't match type ‘Char’ with ‘[Char]’

Tags: haskell

I'm a Haskell beginner and I'm wrestling using functions to modify a list and then return it back to a string. I'm running into this error however. Any advice?

> Couldn't match type 'Char' with '[Char]'
>
> Expected type: String
>
> Actual type: Char

```
createIndex:: String -> String
createIndex str = unLine (removeT (splitLines str))

splitLines:: String -> [String]
splitLines splitStr = lines splitStr

removeT:: [String] -> [String]
removeT strT = filter (=='t') strT

unLine:: [String] -> String
unLine unLinedStr = unlines unLinedStr
```

Comment: This works fine (as in "it type checks", as it will remove all except the `t` lines). Did you accidentally use `=='t'` instead of `== "t"` in your original code?

Comment: whoops, it originally was just 't'. I tried "t" but the problem I had with "t" is it filters out everything so the list becomes empty

Comment: @shamu11 Not everything, just all lines that are not `"t"`.

Comment: That's because `filter p …` will throw away ever `x` where `p x` is `False`, e.g. every line that's not "t".

Comment: so how do I just remove a "t" from each element in the list and the the whole line?

Comment: do you want to remove all `'t'` (then you don't need the lines at all) or just the first `'t'` in each line?

Comment: I just need practice filtering t's from a list of strings so I need to remove any t's from all elements in the list

Comment: than your function is just `createIndex = filter (/= 't')` (type: `String -> String`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your definition of `removeT`. The type of `removeT` is `[String] -> [String]`, meaning it works on a list of lists of characters. Then, in your `filter`, you compare each list of characters (i.e., each `String` in the list) to a `Char` (`'t'`). This is not allowed (you cannot check values with different types for equality).

How to change your code really depends on what you intend to do. It's not entirely clear if you want to remove lines containing t's, if you want to keep lines containing t's, if you want to remove t's, or if you want to keep t's. Depending on what you want to achieve, your code will have to be modified accordingly.

Some pointers:

- If you change the type of `removeT` to `String -> String` you can look at one line at a time. You would then have to replace `removeT` in the definition of `createIndex` by `map removeT` (because you're applying the function to each line)). In this case, the filter would deal with `Char` values so comparing with a 't' is allowed.
- If you want to do something with lines containing t's, `(== 't')` is not the way to go, you will want to use `` ('t' `elem`) `` (meaning "'t' is an element of").
- `filter` keeps elements matching the predicate. So if you want to remove t's from a string for example, you use `filter (/= 't')`.

Comment: I need to remove t's from each one of the string elements in the strings list created by splitLines. what is the best way to do that?

Comment: @shamu11 I answered this above - you don't really need to split here at all - and if you insist on doing you can use `fmap (filter (/= 't'))`

Comment: Right, of course, `filter (/= 't')`, not `filter (not . (== 't'))`, edited. I was half sleeping :)